# ¿Qué palabra se debe usar para "heces"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, sustantivos, formalidad, vulgaridades

En conversación diaria (**ni formal ni vulgar**), ¿que palabra se debe usar para referir a heces? Yo conozco las palabras "heces" (creo que esto es formal, tanto a *feces* en inglés), "caca," "popo," y "mierda" (¿vulgar, tanto a *crap* o peor?). ¿Cuál es el mejor para conversación diaria?

¿Es diferente para las heces de humanos y las heces de animales?

Comment: En la Argentina, *caca* va perfecto. Pero puede ser malsonante para el resto del mundo, como sucede con muchas otras palabras.

Answer (score 2):

Es variable en el país hispanohablante que te encuentres, **pero en México** "mierda" o "caca" son palabras mal sonadas y "excremento" o "heces" suena muy científico.

Para hacer que suene "más agradable" al oído (aunque de por sí su significado no lo sea), en una conversación cotidiana se utiliza "popó" o simplemente se denota la acción como "me estoy haciendo del dos" (del uno: pipí, del dos: popó).

No hay distinción para heces humanas o de animales, a menos que así lo especifiques. Todo se refiere a los residuos sólidos que terminan del proceso de digestión. Simplemente es qué tan bonito, formal o grosero quieres que suene.

Answer (score 0):

### Deposición

> Deposición 
> 1. f. Acción y efecto de deponer.
> 2. f. Evacuación de vientre.

En humanos y animales domésticos, la palabra *deposición* es correcta.
En otros animales: *excrementos* o *defecación*.